# Как узнать индекс тега в массиве DOM?

Tags: dom

Есть множество элементов `h4`
Как узнать индекс определённого тега `h4` в массиве тегов в DOM?

Comment: А для чего вам нужно? Я как-то интересовался подобным вопросом, только мне нужно было узнать позицию в документе относительно других элементов; и сделал это я с помощью сравнения координат элементов в документе.

Comment: $('h4:last').index();

Comment: @Jean-Claude, а как его применить? Извиняюсь, не силён в JS.
При `document.write($('h4:last').index());` ни чего не происходит.

Comment: все инструкции необходимо выполнять после готовности DOM-дерева `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 //выполнить
});`

Comment: @RomanGrinyov, Отслеживать координаты элементов в динамических страницах относительно других и программировать через это всё ссылки? Вы хотите чтобы мой, и без того слабый, мозг совсем взорвался?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, уже понял, что через JQuery. Но мне для разработки (лишь узнать для `getElementsByTagName("h4")[i].innerHTML)`, поэтому прокинул пока временный счётчик: `i=i+1;`.

Comment: *определённого тега h4* - какие у него приметы?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Я-то изначально думал, что из дебаггера браузера, можно это глянуть.

Comment: @splash58 простой `<h4>текст</h4>` их куча, для каждого нужно построить ссылку, вот и понадобился индекс. И то на время отладки скрипта.

Comment: да можно глянуть. xpath постройте. Или просто пальцем по тексту посчитайте. или выполните поиск ао тэгу в дебагере и посчитайте элемент массива

Comment: скажите в консоли `$x('//h4')` выдаст массив. можно там посмотреть

Comment: Я так и не уловил, что вы делаете :) ... [Вот](http://developer.roman.grinyov.name/blog/164) что я делал по координатам. Там в сайдбаре есть карта HTML-заголовков, их соответствующую вложенность и местоположение я определял по координатам в документе.

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.res').append("$('h4:first') " + $('h4:first').index() + '<br>');
  $('.res').append('.last() ' + $('h4').last().index() + '<br>');
  $('.res').append('.filter(".red") ' + $('h4').filter('.red').index() + '<br>');
  $('.res').append('.filter("[name=name]") ' + $('h4').filter('[name=name]').index() + '<br>');
  $('.res').append("$('h4#one') " + $('h4#one').index() + '<br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4>1 заголовок</h4>
<h4 id="one">2 заголовок</h4>
<h4 name="name">3 заголовок</h4>
<h4 class="red">4 заголовок</h4>
<h4>5 заголовок</h4>

<div class="res"></div>
```